# JVisualVM result from Linux server itself

Tags: java, linux

Is there any way to execute and get the result from JVisualVM in Linux server itself?

- We don't have a connection from local to the server directly as there is a proxy restriction.
- Execute the JvisualVM on Linux server and get the result on the same server like jstack.

Comment: please explain bit more clear about your issue ??

Answer (score 0):

You can run the jvisualvm on local machine and connect it to remote server.

Refer to the following screenshot for the same:

[image]

Comment: 's when there is no connection how it would help in access as remote server ??